# Don't Starve getting VERY Choppy framerate

Tags: technical-issues, dont-starve

All right, let me tell you what I know so far.

1. Enabling Vsync and Triple Buffering may help, but my AMD VISION menu doesn't allow me to do that.
2. This game played PERFECTLY on this laptop before, but suddenly started becoming choppy.
3. My video card isn't bad, other games work fine (With the exception of TF2 which gets the same framerate)
4. I don't have a virus.
5. My specs are:

   - Processor: AMD E2-1800 APU with Radeon HD graphics 1.70 GHz
   - RAM: 4.00 GB
   - OS: 64-bit Windows 8

Someone please help. I've been everywhere.

Comment: First things first, are your video card drivers up to date? If not, update them.

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I did when I found out about my little problem.

Comment: Ok it's down to guessing then. Have you tried uninstalling the game and then reinstalling it? It's possible something messed up the files.

Comment: I've tried uninstalling and re-installing, validating files, and defragging.

Comment: I can hardly imagine you didn't, but have you tried running as administrator, compatibility mode, disable display scaling?

Comment: Is this the Chrome or Steam version? Is your machine running hot?

Comment: Another suggestion, you mentioned you are playing on a laptop, is the power plan maybe set to 'power saving'? If yes, try setting it to 'high performance' instead.

Comment: I've tried all of these things. Also, it's the steam version.

Comment: Did the game get an update before you encountered these problems?

Comment: Actually, Yes! This started happening after the most recent update.

Comment: Chances are the update broke something. I tried searching for it on google, but I didn't find anything useful. I did find [this post](http://forums.kleientertainment.com/showthread.php?12334-A-Little-Rain-Must-Fall-Release-Notes/page1) about the update, and more people seem to have problems with it. I suggest you wait for a new update for now.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help, I'll just wait for the next update to un-break my game. c:

Comment: Have such a problem, too. It occurs "randomly" after some time playing (sometimes at day 3, sometimes at day 7, sometimes never). To me it looks like a memory leak. After quitting and restarting the game, everything is fine … until it happens again.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue along with really bizarre graphics.

I solved it by:

1. Right click on desktop, choose your graphics card control panel
2. Tell it to use integrated graphics instead of your normal graphics card

Or, simply tell your graphics cards not to use Bilinear nor Trilinear filtering.

Answer (score 0):

Did they patch it recently? It could be something they did to the game, I've had that problem with Chivalry. I have to turn all of the video options to low or off in order to be able to play that game now. Try tweaking any in-game settings they give you to see if it will improve performance.

You can also try setting your desktop background to black - this is a trick I picked up back in the mmo days. If you have a large file as your desktop bg it requires more resources from your computer.